# Reactive Streams crazy card select sphagetti action

Tags: javascript, rxjs, bacon.js

I have two cards, I want to select (highlight) a card when it is clicked.
If I mouse down on a card when there is a selection I want to move the selected card onto this one and not make a selection on mouse up (or click).

What I have tried:

```
let esStarts = Bacon.fromEvent('mousedown');

let esClicks = Bacon.fromEvent('click');

// event stream to select (highlight) a card
let esPersistSelect = esClicks
    // .takeUntil(esMovePersistSelect);

let pPersistSelect = Bacon.update({},
    [esPersistSelect, fSelectCard]);

// event stream to move a card on mouse down while persist select is active
let esMovePersistSelect = esStarts.flatMap(startSelect =>
    pPersistSelect.take(1)
        .flatMap(persistSelect =>
        Bacon.once({ move:
            { src: startSelect, dst:persistSelect } });
);
```

Comment: can you add a stackblitz for that ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-mvsgfw @bubbles